# Bootstrap 4 pills with Angular - keep active link

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-routing, angular8

I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills">
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">
          <i class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i> Home
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive="active">
        <i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog"></i> Settings
    </a>
  </nav>
```

I am using routerLinkActive to keep active links active when I reload the page. But when I click on another control (like dropdown) the active link loses a focus and it's not highlighted anymore. Is there "Angular" way to keep it selected in the same way when a page is reloaded?

Thanks

Comment: are you tried to add the same styles to the `.active` class? for example 
`.active { outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color; }`

Comment: Doesn't look like it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your link tag if it helps:

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it helps.